# nohoist with workspaces still hoisting

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Inside my Monorepo I have one packages in which I want all the dependencies inside its node_modules.

But whatever I do, it's node_modules remains empty.

So, for the purpose of my question I was able to reproduce the issue with the following setup

```
/
 package.json
 lerna.json
 node_modules
 packages/
          A/
            node_modules
            package.json
            index.ts
          B/
            node_modules
            package.json
            index.ts
```

I've created a [repo](https://github.com/scaljeri/nohoist) for this!

Main package.json

```
{
  "name": "A-B-test",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": ["packages/*"],
    "nohoist": [ "**/B" ]
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.13.4"
  }
}
```

`B/package.json` looks like

```
{
  "name": "@scaljeri/B",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  }
}
```

Now when I run `yarn` in the root of the project, all dependencies are installed in the root `node_modules`.

yarn version: 1.16.0
node: 12.4.0

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

Comment: For anyone else who is on Yarn version 2 or higher: "workspaces.nohoist" has been replaced with "installConfig.hoistingLimits". 

https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/manifest#installConfig

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In my experience, it has been necessary to doubly specify each package in the following manner:

```json
{
  "nohoist": [
    "**/B",
    "**/B/**",
    "**/C",
    "**/C/**"
  ]
}
```

In addition, I have found it necessary to delete all existing `node_modules` folders after modifying the `nohoist` settings. So, if your projects are in `packages`, and you are in your project directory, you can delete all of those `node_modules` folders like this:

```
# delete node_modules on linux
rm -rf ./packages/*/node_modules
rm -rf ./node_modules

# install again
yarn install --check-files
```

Comment: I also had to delete my `yarn.lock` file to get Yarn to not hoist a package.

Comment: you can also clean up all node modules of packages through `lerna clean` which will let you also select the ones you want to really clean up

Answer (score 21):

I tried a few options but the only one that finally worked for me was specifying the `nohoist` option in the child package. No need to specify anything at the root level.
So my `package.json` in `B` package is:

```json
{
...

  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": ["**"]
  },

...
}
```

Comment: this one should be marked as correct answer. None of above worked for me.

Comment: Also package should have private: "true" in order for this to work

Answer (score 5):

Applying the nohoist to the child package's package.json did it for me.

```
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "*react-native*",
      "*react-native*/**"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked with yarn 1.22. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me (1.22.4). Yarn showed an error because the child package was not `private`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude package B node modules  from hoisting you can do that in you package.json:

```
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "**/B",
      "**/B/**"
    ]
  },
```

after that remove **node_modules** and **yarn.lock** and run `yarn install` again now you should see packages/B/node_modules not being hoisted to the top level of the project

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me on yarn 3.6.4 was adding `nmHoistingLimits: workspaces` to my root `.yarnrc.yml` file