# Make Yarn don't hoist the dependencies of the specific package

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

In below project, I want all dependencies of `TodoList` will no be hosted to `node_modules`  in root directory of monorepo.

[image]

Below settings is not enough to reach this effect:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [ "BusinessRules", "Server", "TodoList" ],
    "nohoist": [
      "TodoList/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

`"TodoList/**/**"` is not enough too.

How to make all dependencies of `TodoList` will be inside `TodoList/node_modules`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66861554/4818123).

In this case, it's required to add below JSON in `TodoList/package.json`:

```json
"workspaces": {
    "nohoist": ["**"]
},
```